# find a piece of JavaScript in Firebug's Script tab

Tags: firebug

How to find a particular piece of JavaScript (e.g. a function) in Firebug's Script tab?  There doesn't seem to be a way to do a Ctrl-F type of Find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Find box in the upper-right hand corner:

[image: Find box]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/img/js/screenScript-linejump.gif))</sub>